# Is there a way to see who created which tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Is there a way that a person can know who created which tag?

Comment: Marking this [meta-tag:status-declined] in light of Jeff's MSO post linked to in the answer here and the status-declined tag on *that* question.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it appears there's no official way to find the information (and there are [no plans for it either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created/6822#6822) due to gaming concerns).

There are some "[unofficial ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/how-does-one-find-which-tags-they-created)" though:

- Tag -> sort by newest -> last page -> question on the bottom, should be the earliest question asked with that tag, but still not guaranteed that that question or that user created the tag. [from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/how-does-one-find-which-tags-they-created/10898#10898)]
- See who won the [Taxonimist badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/11/taxonomist) (you have to have created it to win it!)

Comment: Why are there more gaming concerns with seeing who created a tag over seeing how many votes a person got for a question or answer?

Comment: @Gershon They're afraid if someone knows he/she created a tag, they will then begin using the tag all over to get Taxonimist badge. Not sure what the voting problem would be. Can you elaborate

Comment: A person can also just remember that he created the tag and do that?

Comment: If the tag is not used appropiately then it will be deleted from the entry and take away the badge?

Comment: @Gershon I'm just saying why *they* don't want it. I don't necessarily agree with them. They also mention that the data won't be of any benefit. If you'd like you can take this up on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: There would be a benefit to the person who created the tag knowing how many questions were asked with the tag he created.

Comment: @Gershon Okay, and what would that give the user?

Comment: A good feeling knowing that the tag he created is being used